# Parsing complex JSON in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The list of maps that I get as a http response

```
    final List<dynamic> scoresByDay = httpResponse[0]['days']['averageScores'];    
    print(scoresByDay);
```

looks like:

```
   [
     {"date":"27\/08\/2019","score":"30.00"},
     {"date":"28\/08\/2019","score":"67.67"},
     {"date":"29\/08\/2019","score":"73.00"},
     {"date":"30\/08\/2019","score":"59.80"},
     {"date":"31\/08\/2019","score":"57.18"},
     {"date":"01\/09\/2019","score":"50.75"},
     {"date":"02\/09\/2019","score":"50.78"},
     {"date":"03\/09\/2019","score":"50.85"},
     {"date":"04\/09\/2019","score":"48.18"},
     {"date":"05\/09\/2019","score":"58.12"}
    ]
```

What I would like to get from this json array is a list that I can use for Flutter Charting library (Simple Bar Chart).
In order to use this Simple Bar Chart this array should look like this:

```
     final data = [
          new OrdinalSales('27', 30),
          new OrdinalSales('28', 68),
          new OrdinalSales('29', 74),
          new OrdinalSales('30', 60),
          new OrdinalSales('31', 57),
          new OrdinalSales('01', 51),
          new OrdinalSales('02', 51),
          new OrdinalSales('03', 51),
          new OrdinalSales('04', 48),
          new OrdinalSales('05', 58),

];
```

Is there any way to use the existing list of maps to create the json array that I need to display the Simple Bar Chart?

EDIT:

I managed to create an array (simpleBarArrayData) with the data I needed for the Simple Bar Chart (https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/simple). But when I try to insert that array instead of the array set as an example in Simple Bar Chart an error occurs:

```
    type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type List<OrdinalSales>'
```

The example data array:

```
    final data = [
      new OrdinalSales('27', 30),
      new OrdinalSales('28', 68),
      new OrdinalSales('29', 74),
      new OrdinalSales('30', 60),
      new OrdinalSales('31', 57),
      new OrdinalSales('01', 51),
      new OrdinalSales('02', 51),
      new OrdinalSales('03', 51),
      new OrdinalSales('04', 48),
      new OrdinalSales('05', 58),
    ];
```

The created array (simpleBarArrayData) looks like this:

```
   print(simpleBarArrayData);

    [
     new OrdinalSales('27',30), 
     new OrdinalSales('28',68), 
     new OrdinalSales('29',73), 
     new OrdinalSales('30',60), 
     new OrdinalSales('31',57), 
     new OrdinalSales('01',51), 
     new OrdinalSales('02',51), 
     new OrdinalSales('03',51), 
     new OrdinalSales('04',48), 
     new OrdinalSales('05',58)
    ]
```

I tried to replace the existing data with the following code:

```
    final data = simpleBarArrayData;
```

And the error occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure why the answers not mention about the greatest official [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json), It's easy to use generator instead of custom hard coding...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your

```
List json = [YOUR_GIVEN_JSON_IN_LIST];
```

You can create this method, and here dates will only have your `dates` and `scores` have score.

```
List<String> dates = [];
List<int> scores = [];

void _fetch() {
  for (var item in json) {
    String date = item["date"];
    dates.add(date.split("\/")[0]);

    String score = item["score"];
    int element = int.parse(score.split("\.")[0]);
    scores.add(element);
  }
}

void _merge() {
  // you can merge by iterating it over
  List<OrdinalSales> data = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    data.add(OrdinalSales(dates[i], scores[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I merge these two arrays and get a string "new OrdinalSales('27', 30)" inlcuded in that new array?

Comment: Still without the right solution to the problem. I edited the question with my attempt to solve it.

Comment: OK, the fix should be easy, instead of using `List<OrdinalSales>` use `List<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

Given an `OrdinalSales` example specification like

```dart
class OrdinalSales {
  String day;
  num score;

  OrdinalSales.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>  m){
    day = m["date"].substring(0,2); // serious date parsing should be here
    score = num.parse(m["score"]).round();
  }
}
```

you can use it like

```dart
List<dynamic> scoresByDay = [
     {"date":"27\/08\/2019","score":"30.00"},
     {"date":"28\/08\/2019","score":"67.67"},
     {"date":"29\/08\/2019","score":"73.00"},
     {"date":"30\/08\/2019","score":"59.80"},
     {"date":"31\/08\/2019","score":"57.18"},
     {"date":"01\/09\/2019","score":"50.75"},
     {"date":"02\/09\/2019","score":"50.78"},
     {"date":"03\/09\/2019","score":"50.85"},
     {"date":"04\/09\/2019","score":"48.18"},
     {"date":"05\/09\/2019","score":"58.12"}
    ];
// parse j with
var result = scoresByDay.map((i) => OrdinalSales.fromMap(i)).toList();
print(result[0].day); // 27
print(result[0].score); // 30
```

Comment: I get this error "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<OrdinalSales>'"

Comment: Where? (I made a small refactor so that the code should be more understeable).

Comment: I just edited the question with my attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Try using `data = new List.from(simpleBarArrayData);`.
If `data` was defined as `final` this won't work and you have to either remove the `final` keyword or create another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here the model for your json

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final ordinalSales = ordinalSalesFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<OrdinalSales> ordinalSalesFromJson(String str) => 
new List<OrdinalSales>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => 
OrdinalSales.fromJson(x)));

String ordinalSalesToJson(List<OrdinalSales> data) => 
json.encode(new List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class OrdinalSales {
String date;
String score;

OrdinalSales({
    this.date,
    this.score,
});

factory OrdinalSales.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
new OrdinalSales(
    date: json["date"] == null ? null : json["date"],
    score: json["score"] == null ? null : json["score"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "date": date == null ? null : date,
    "score": score == null ? null : score,
};
}
```

you can use below URL to create a model for JSON
https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)